# Appbar should be overlapped when scrolling

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I want to achieve the following behavior, When I start scrolling the appbar should go behind the content.

Someone SliverAppbar works, but as it has minExtent in _SliverAppbarDelegate, It shrinks the size of the Appbar which I don't want.

https://gifyu.com/image/Sdh84

````
Stack(
            children: [
              Positioned.fill(
                top: 0,
                child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                  child: SizedBox(
                    height: kToolbarHeight + context.padding.top,
                    child: CustomAppBar(
                      title: TranslationConstants.dashboard,
                      hasDrawer: true,
                      onLeadingTap: () => setState(() {
                        print("Leading");
                        zoomControllerIconChanger = true;
                        if (drawerController.toggle != null) {
                          drawerController.toggle!();
                        }
                      }),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Positioned.fill(
                top: kToolbarHeight + context.padding.top,
                child: ListView.builder(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                  itemCount: 100,
                  itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
                    return ListTile(
                        title: Text('ELEMENT $topPosition -> $index'));
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
    ```
    Here is my code
````

Answer (score 0):

Instead of providing `top: kToolbarHeight + context.padding.top` you can the `ListView.builders`'s padding.

```dart
Positioned.fill(
  child: ListView.builder(
    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
        top: // this one 
        ),
    itemCount: 100,
```

Comment: Didn't work, I tried it

Comment: , can you provide minimal widget